# weight not work in Liner layout in android studio

Tags: android, android-layout

I want my app to show pics. the pics should be larger in size and pic description will be just under them like Instagram. But its not working for me with my code.
my current result looks like :

[image]
 this is my code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">



<LinearLayout
android:layout_weight="2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/ivFish"/>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="fish name"
        android:id="@+id/textFishName"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/ivFish"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textPrice"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="price"
        android:id="@+id/textPrice"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="Small Text"
        android:id="@+id/textSize"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/textFishName"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/ivFish"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/ivFish"
        android:textColor="#666"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="sd"
        android:id="@+id/textType"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/textSize"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/ivFish"
        android:textColor="#666"/>

</LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Try to add this android:scaleType="fitXY" property to ImageView

Answer (score 1):

If you need to show image as `match_parent` then you need to add `android:scaleType` property with `fitXY`value into ImageView as below :

```
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:id="@+id/ivFish"/>
```

Comment: i try this : <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_gravity="center" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="0dp" android:layout_weight="1"> <ImageView android:scaleType="fitXY" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:id="@+id/ivFish"/> </LinearLayout> but my pics so large!

Comment: Try to provide some fix height to ImageView which shown Image properly.

Answer (score 1):

As I see, you want to crop empty space around your image. If I'm correct, you need to add

```
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```

to your ImageView. The you should add your desire scaleType also.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing weightSum property for the parent layout.

android:layout_weight works with  android:weightSum . so add WeightSum to parent layout first.

Answer (score 0):

You are complicating the layout unnecessary with two Linear Layout.

If you need to align the image to occupy the width and all text below that image one by one , then the following will work.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/ivFish"
        android:src="@drawable/icon"
        android:gravity="center"
        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="fish name"
        android:id="@+id/textFishName"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="price"
        android:id="@+id/textPrice"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="Small Text"
        android:id="@+id/textSize"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:textColor="#666"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="sd"
        android:id="@+id/textType"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:textColor="#666"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: height=100dp! is wrong i want use this app for another phons with diffrent screens . so its not usefull

Comment: I am helping you to resolve your problem . You see how it looks after copy pasting my code. Then you can modify!  If you want to use weight, then that also can be achieved. Let me know if you want :)

Comment: thanks for helping but i know this way! not standard way

Comment: @erfan  Hope you are happy now with weight :) Happy Standard coding

Answer (score 0):

Try using Recycler view with custom adapter:

https://www.sitepoint.com/mastering-complex-lists-with-the-android-recyclerview/

https://guides.codepath.com/android/using-the-recyclerview